# Some classes of semiprimitive pm-rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

A commutative ring  with 1 is called semiprimitive  whenever $J(R)=\cap_{m\in Max(R)}m=0$, and a ring is called a Gelfand ring (or a pm ring) if each
prime ideal is contained in a unique maximal ideal. It is well known von Neumann regular rings and $C(X)$ ( ring of continuous functions over $X$) are two classes of semiprimitive Gelfand rings. I am looking for some other famous classes of such rings?

Comment: That's pretty narrow. The von Neumann regular rings already exhaust the zero-dimensional case.  I don't understand the prime ideals of $C(X)$ to know why that example works. How do you see that?